# Axis Fault- java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

When I'm trying to hit soap service I am getting this exception in liferay 7.

Axis jar already available in tomcat/web-inf/lib folder. I'm using `compileOnly` in `build.gradle`.

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.axis.attachments.Attachments
    at org.apache.axis.Message.setup(Message.java:352)
```

Comment: That kind of ClassCastException signals that you have these classes twice on your classpath and the interface is loaded through one location while the implementation is implementing the other alternative interface. The errormessage only states the interface name, not the classloader. Figure out which one of the jars you have on the classpath is superfluous and remove it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liferay - Creating PDF and outputing to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839713/liferay-creating-pdf-and-outputing-to-stream). While technically this question/answer looks completely different, the underlying principle, e.g. the duplicate class on the classpath, is the same. This is the case where a subclass appears to not be castable to its legitimate superclass/interface.

Comment: Did you find the cause and fix for this issue?

We are facing the same issue and on looking into the code we have compileOnly in the custom service's build.gradle and there is no other version of the axis used in the complete application. On searching the jar in the complete bundle we see the following two places axis.jar is available:

\bundles\tomcat-9.0.6\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib => axis.jar
\bundles\osgi\state\org.eclipse.osgi\1033\0\.cp\lib => org.apache.axis-1.4.LIFERAY-PATCHED-2.jar

Any pointers would be a great help!